SSRS data driven subscription, intermittent werid error rsInvalidReportParameter
Trying to troubleshoot weird intermittent error no my demo simple SSRS report, it supposed to run for 10 params, and send email to 10 users, but I have only 3/10 sometime 5/10, sometime 1/10 success rate.
Notice that even changing case on  my single @user param makes difference, which is totally absurd, as I'm on SQL 2021 with normal collation , I can run successfully report with all 10 params from SSMS without any problems and I'm getting feedback.
Traced it into ReportServer log where some params recorded  with status  rsInvalidReportParameter, but some param never reach ReportServer.
 SELECT TOP 120 c.[Name],        el.UserName,        el.[Parameters],       el.TimeStart, Status
FROM starreport.ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog el
INNER JOIN starreport.ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c ON el.ReportID = c.ItemID
WHERE c.[Name] LIKE '%rrc%'--' '%Sec%'
ORDER BY  el.TimeStart DESC

*I'on Microsoft SQL Server 2019,  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
I did my homework and found that it's happening for others too.  Anybody has any ideas how I can troubleshoot this, I've opened ticket with MS but they didn't reply.
*This error not about  Outlook/Email server error, I tried do Windows FileShare distribution and it's the same. some params just don't reach  ReportServer and no any traces about them are present in any logs.
Thanks
Mario
